# Cannot access results of find module using with_items loop

Tags: ansible

I am trying to iterate through a list of lists (I have a bunch of items that return list context) in ansible 2.3.x. I want to take action based upon the results of a register variable, but I can't seem to get to the base elements when using my `with_items`. I have tried mapping as in my code below but cannot ever get access to the attribute 'path' in the registered results (over which I want to iterate using `with_items`).

```
#!/bin/ansible-playbook
---
- name: Check state of repos and prevent updates
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  vars:
    basecomponents:
      - cbr
      - slc
      - gts
      - vep
      - mcp
      - lse

  tasks:

  - name: Create and enable repo if necessary
    yum_repository:
      name: MyRepo
      description: My Repo
      baseurl: http://127.0.0.1/repo/head/myrepo/x86_64/
      enabled: yes
      gpgcheck: yes
      mirrorlist_expire: 60
      state: present
  - name: remove update from last version
    find:
      paths: "/home/{{item}}/update/"
      patterns: "currentVersion.*"
    with_items: "{{basecomponents}}"
    register: findresult

   - name: remove current version
     file:
      path: "{{item.path}}"
      state: absent
     with_items: findresult.results.

  - name: Debug result
    debug:
      var: "{{item.files}}"
    with_items:
      - findresult.results
      # | map(attribute='path')| list}}
```

Here are the results when I run things:

```
ok: [localhost] => (item=findresult.results) => {
    "findresult.results": [
        {
            "_ansible_item_result": true, 
            "_ansible_no_log": false, 
            "_ansible_parsed": true, 
            "changed": false, 
            "examined": 4, 
            "files": [
                {
                    "atime": 1500919313.0, 
                    "ctime": 1500919690.9134178, 
                    "dev": 64774, 
                    "gid": 1002, 
                    "inode": 94371970, 
                    "isblk": false, 
                    "ischr": false, 
                    "isdir": false, 
                    "isfifo": false, 
                    "isgid": false, 
                    "islnk": false, 
                    "isreg": true, 
                    "issock": false, 
                    "isuid": false, 
                    "mode": "0664", 
                    "mtime": 1500919313.0, 
                    "nlink": 1, 
                    "path": "/home/cbr/update/currentVersion.1500918030", 
                    "rgrp": true, 
                    "roth": true, 
                    "rusr": true, 
                    "size": 0, 
                    "uid": 1001, 
                    "wgrp": true, 
                    "woth": false, 
                    "wusr": true, 
                    "xgrp": false, 
                    "xoth": false, 
                    "xusr": false
                }, 
                {
                    "atime": 1500919313.0, 
                    "ctime": 1500919690.9134178, 
                    "dev": 64774, 
                    "gid": 1002, 
                    "inode": 94371969, 
                    "isblk": false, 
                    "ischr": false, 
                    "isdir": false, 
                    "isfifo": false, 
                    "isgid": false, 
                    "islnk": false, 
                    "isreg": true, 
                    "issock": false, 
                    "isuid": false, 
                    "mode": "0664", 
                    "mtime": 1500919313.0, 
                    "nlink": 1, 
                    "path": "/home/cbr/update/currentVersion.1500919311", 
                    "rgrp": true, 
                    "roth": true, 
                    "rusr": true, 
                    "size": 0, 
                    "uid": 1001, 
                    "wgrp": true, 
                    "woth": false, 
                    "wusr": true, 
                    "xgrp": false, 
                    "xoth": false, 
                    "xusr": false
                }
            ], 
            "invocation": {
                "module_args": {
                    "age": null, 
                    "age_stamp": "mtime", 
                    "contains": null, 
                    "file_type": "file", 
                    "follow": false, 
                    "get_checksum": false, 
                    "hidden": false, 
                    "paths": [
                        "/home/cbr/update/"
                    ], 
                    "patterns": [
                        "currentVersion.*"
                    ], 
                    "recurse": false, 
                    "size": null, 
                    "use_regex": false
                }
            }, 
            "item": "cbr", 
            "matched": 2, 
            "msg": ""
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your last task was very close.  You just need to flip path and files.

```
- name: Debug result
  debug:
    var: "{{item.path}}"
  with_items: "{{ findresult.results | map(attribute='files') | list}}
```

Alternatively you could use `with_subelements`

```
- name: Debug result
  debug:
    msg: "{{ item.1.path }}"
  with_subelements:
  - "{{ findresult.results }}"
  - files
```

Comment: Thanks so much!  Your map attributes solution fixed a problem I've been tinkering with for about two days!

Answer (score 1):

The attributes 'path' that you want to access belong to every element of the **list** indexed by the **key** 'files'.
In your task "remove update from last version variable" you register `findresult`, which is a dictionary.

```
  - name: remove update from last version
    find:
      paths: "/home/{{item}}/update/"
      patterns: "currentVersion.*"
    with_items: "{{basecomponents}}"
    register: findresult
```

So, in order to loop over the 'path' attributes you need to first **get the list using the key**, like this:

```
   - name: remove current version
     file:
       path: "{{ item.path }}"
       state: absent
     with_items: "{{ findresult['files'] }}"
```